# Display Buffering/Loading message in Shiny Dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, dashboard, shinydashboard

I have done Shiny dashboard with 4 different tabs in the Side panel. It's all working perfectly fine. The only thing is, the fourth tab is a plotly output. When I click the tab, it should display the entire US county map.

It takes nearly 30 seconds to load the map after the tab button is clicked. Until that the screen just displays the empty body background. **Is there anyway I could add a buffering/loading message that gets displayed in the body until the map is loaded**? So that the user knows that the map is being loaded.. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://deanattali.com/blog/advanced-shiny-tips/#plot-spinner)?

Comment: or [this?](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/progress.html)

Answer (score 2):

Alternate to the progress bar there are few things you can do in this regard.

```
library(shinycssloaders)
usage: 
withSpinner(plotOutput("my_plot"))
plotOutput("my_plot") %>% withSpinner()
```

If it takes 30 secs you may want to look into the Asynchronous concept in Rshiny Conference. [Joe Cheng talk](https://www.rstudio.com/resources/videos/scaling-shiny-apps-with-async-programming/)

probably [this](https://github.com/r-lib/async) is still probably work in progress, but you can find alternate options will be available.